# DB2 Data copy from prod to Stage environment

Tags: java, db2

I am new to DB2 using TOAD 6 VERSION  and trying to (data refresh )copy the records from prod env to Stage env , My prod env and stage env are in different servers with different schemas , Is there any possible way to do cross connection or db link between prod and test env to copy paste the records ( or delta of records ) .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What Db2 version are you using? Have you considered using Federation? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002170.html?pos=2